# Override background image/color in the community using the Napili template

Tags: css, community, napili, template

I've been testing the customization capabilities of communities with napili template. One of the very basic things I cannot easily do is, branding. I can update the logo, but not the background. It seems I need to override the CSS, found the below snippet that helps to change the background,

.default-bg-overlay {
    background: white none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
}

The above one change the header color, but not the body, I also cannot set the background image. What would be the right way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

To update the background, in the branding editor, there should be an "edit" pencil or brush referring to "Edit CSS"

[image]

from there you can change the background with appropriate css styling.

for Ex.

```
body
{
background: red;
}
```

You should see your "body" change color.

Please refer to [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize_css.htm) documentation for further customizations.

UPDATE (Witner '18):

Lightning Communities now support changing the background color from the Branding Editor's properties:

[image]

Comment: The guide you linked to has now been retired - current one is at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.community_templates.meta/community_templates/rss_planning_ahead.htm otherwise good answer.

Comment: Thanks @Dave Humm, I have updated the link in the answer.

Comment: @glls This workaround works just fine. BUT, whenever the community page loads for the first time, header background would come up with GRAY color and then applies/re-renders to the color we had in the Custom Css. This makes end users to see color switch and that doesn't seem good at all.

Comment: This doesn't apply to the standard components background color that are placed in the community pages.

Comment: not with LWC, in the past, with Aura, the css could be overriden, but because of Shadow DOM, this is no longer possible