# Is there a way to remove the edit/new/delete buttons in the related list view of record detail in lightning community?

Tags: community, lightning

[image]

Is there a way to remove the edit/new/delete buttons in the related list view of record detail in lightning community? I know that it's not in the object layout and I also can't change the profile.

Comment: can you not restrict the profile and provide a permission set with all the CRUD access?

Answer (score 1):

You can select the standard layout property :
[image]

and apply a CSS rule to disable the pointer event:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

to the appropriate scope.

Please note css rules are not a best practice...

Comment: Css rule in standard lightning pages !?

Comment: @Ankuli, you can add them using the branding editor, you can check https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130744/override-background-image-color-in-the-community-using-the-napili-template/149929#149929 for reference